# change div width using media queries when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I would like to write a media query to set a different width for a div when resizing the browser. I want this to do because my bootstrap not gonna work as intended. Any help ?

html :

```
<div class = "column2 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
    <ng-view> Loading.. </ng-view>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column2
{
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 535px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow-y: auto;  /* Makes the scrollbar appear when it should be scrollable */
}
```

I want this to happen when browser width is less than 600px.

Comment: Well, yes, use a media query. You seem to have answered your own question - excep your code doesn't contain any media queries.

Comment: @Utkanos I'm not very familiar with media queries. Can you tell me the way how to do that?

Comment: Did you research? This is pretty much the simplest kind of MQ and would appear in any introductory tutorial.

Comment: I did,  but not much because I don't have enough time. I don't understand this max-width scenario. I found the solution by the way. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

    .column2
    {
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 535px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow-y: auto;  /* Makes the scrollbar appear when it should be      scrollable */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column2
{
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 535px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow-y: auto;  /* Makes the scrollbar appear when it should be scrollable */
}

}
```